# Is using Redirection to print to file in C++ faster than using the convectional cout?

Tags: c++, printf, cout, io-redirection

I'm working on a  code that performs the Josephus's permutation. I noticed that when I use redirection, its faster than when I use `cout` or `printf`. Please I would like to know from anyone having experience, which one is usually faster as i am mostly concerned with code performance and timing.

Thanks.

Comment: Define "faster", the delay is probably because **you're printing stuff to the console window**, if you don't need the info don't print anything or dump it to `/dev/nul` / `NUL`. That said I'm sure `std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false)` will help if you aren't already using it (and you don't need to mix `printf` with `cout`).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your OS an your platform's implementation of the C and C++ I/O libraries (... and cpu load, services, processes, RAM...).

On Windows, writing to the console is a huge bottleneck. Usually it's faster on Linux / MacOS (e.g. [Performance difference of iostream console output between Windows and OSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17817456/performance-difference-of-iostream-console-output-between-windows-and-osx)).

Writing to an `ofstream` directly could increase performance if it uses a different buffering scheme compared to `cout` (and this is often the case).

Anyway with `streams` you can speed up the printing significantly using `'\n'` instead of `std::endl`:

```
  std::cout << "Test line\n";
```

is faster than:

```
std::cout << "Test line" << std::endl;
```

since the latter is equivalent to:

```
std::cout << "Test line\n" << std::flush;
```

(see [C++: "std::endl" vs "\n"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/c-stdendl-vs-n) for further details).

Some references:

- [C++ does printing to terminal significantly slow down code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487568/c-does-printing-to-terminal-significantly-slow-down-code)
- [Printing to the console vs writing to a file (speed)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6338812/printing-to-the-console-vs-writing-to-a-file-speed)
- [Writing to standard out vs writing to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13920208/writing-to-standard-out-vs-writing-to-file?lq=1)

Comment: @peter, thanks a lot, i was able to make if faster using \n, i also see the difference now on linux and macOS. cuz i tried it on different platforms, although i mostly work with windows.